# hover button image not fit for all menus?

Tags: html, css, background, hover

I have a menu on which I have to make a hover effect, that can't be drawn by css, so I have  use it as a picture. My menu objects are `<li>` objects with different sizes, [image]

and I cant understand how can I make the different sized images fit in `<li>` because the `<li>` objects don't have a defined width.

My code is as follows:

```
ul li:hover{

    background:url('../images/hover.jpg');
        width:100%;


}
```

but it sets the picture to `<ul>` size and repeats it over and over

Comment: did you try background-size:100%?

Comment: try background-repeat : no-repeat; so image will appear only once

Comment: try background-size: 100% or cover;

Comment: already tried background-size:100%, didnt help, because if the menu object is smaller, it just make the hover small in width and height, meaning sometimes the hover is repeated in height : http://i.imgur.com/a9rncuy.jpg

Comment: even with no-repeat, it still make the hover small in height

Comment: background-size: 100% will only make it 100% width. background: cover will make it 100% width or height - depends on the proportions. background: 100% 100% will make the background always the size of the container.

Comment: hmmm, can you set the `background-size` as yoor image size? try to hard code size. like this  `background-size: Widthpx Heightpx`;

Comment: if you read the question, you will see that the menu items differ in size. Hardcoding them wont work. 
Just have a look at the Demo in my answer.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to put `div` elements inside the `li` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I cropped the mid part of the hover image, and cropped the end and the start. i used the mid as background and set on repeat, then put 2 divs with end at start with `position:absolute` and `left:0px;` and `right:0px;`  worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use @font-face to include a font that has support for those characters, and have the menu items using that font. Then you could have something like:

```
ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but fonts are not the problem here, its only about setting the size of the hover. and drawing it in css is impossible due to the outline that is sideways :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

[**Demo**](http://liveweave.com/gP1oK6)

[Learn more about `background`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)